# Setting The Default Value Of ASP.NET Controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, default-value, web-controls

Suppose we have `<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ... />` and we want to the default value of `Display` to be `Dynamic`. I couldn't think of any better way to set it than

```css
span[style="visibility:hidden;"],span[style="visibility: hidden;"] {
    display:none;
}
```

and I didn't find anything (simple) in Google. What do you recommend?

Comment: As a workaround, you could just create an event handler that walks the control tree and sets your default, and register it as the `Init` handler for every page. It's a little hackish and not devoid of boilerplate, but it could do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a [theme with a skin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ykzx33wh.aspx) for `asp:RequiredFieldValidator` and set its `Display` property to `Dynamic`. Then each page you set to have that theme will default its validators to `Display = "Dynamic"`.

Note that if you set the `SkinID` on the validator in the skin template, then you will also have to set the `SkinID` on all `asp:RequiredFieldValidor`s you use throughout your page(s). If you really want every validator to default to dynamic, don't set a `SkinID`.